# reading a string of expected pattern

Tags: c, input, format

I wanted to know about the possible ways to read a string from input that conforms to a specific pattern. more specific I want to check for correct pattern

For example if I expect a command like "multiply 5, 6" and I want to ignore white space but to check for correct pattern so I want to seperate "multiply" "5," and "6" from input stream to check validity for each

Is there a way to do that with scanf? or gets?

thanks

Comment: There are countless existing questions on reading and matching strings. And even the `scanf` man page alone gives more than enough info for you to answer that part of your question. Have you done any basic research or searches?

Comment: Actually I did searched and researched but could not understand the answers. I just started learning C and the explenations are not yet clear to me.
I dont understand the harsh attitude though, I thought this is a place to ask questions and learn. thanks anyway, I'll be sure to become an expert before posting another question.

Comment: It's not about being an expert. It's about doing basic research and asking a clear question. If you have an idea that `scanf` would work then study the man page carefully, search for examples and write some code to try it out. The best way to learn is to attempt to do it yourself. If the code you write doesn't work and you can't work out why then come back to show your code and ask a specific question about that code. As it is, your question is not worded in a way that makes it clear which specific part of the problem you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will do what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int num1, num2;
  char operation[15];
  printf("\nPlease Enter Input: ");
  scanf("%s%d ,%d",operation,&num1,&num2); // note the space before the comma
  printf("\nYou entered \"%s %d,%d\"\n",operation,num1,num2);

  return 0;
}
```

Running this code produces the following (output varies depending on input):

```
Please Enter Input: multiply 5,6

You entered "multiply 5,6"
```

Running it again with spaces in different parts of input:

```
Please Enter Input:     multiply      8    ,     120

You entered "multiply 8,120"
```

Run this code and try removing the space before the comma in the scanf and see what happens when you input "multiply 5 ,7"

- Note: %s and %d automatically ignore leading whitespace.

There are many fancy things you can do to get scanf to accept specially formatted input.  If you have any other specific questions, feel free to ask.

Reference (c++ site, but same function as c):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/